# Creating and Calling multiple Dialogs using luis intent in microsoft bot builder v4

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm working on a project that requires i create a commerce chatbot and i'm using microsoft bot framework SDK V4. when a chat is initiated,after greetings intents is handled, the bot displays the services it offers(Products, Enquiry) using adaptive card and card actions. Now here is the challenge i am having, I created different dialogs to handle different services the bot offer(ProductDialog, EnquiryDialog), The ProductDialog displays five services/products the bot offer, (question 1) how do i make the product dialog dispaly this services using card action.

Now the second and main challenge is after displaying this services and a user chooses one, how do i forward his choice to its respective dialog to handle, lets say the five services are CustomerService, InsuranceService, HospitalService, SchoolService, BillingService and i created a dialog.cs class for them respectively, how do i call this dialogs from the ProductDialog.

I don't know if my explanation is clear enough.

Comment: You should post the code you already have and describe your problem on the basis of your code.

Comment: Agreed with fridoo, you should post code that you already have. Additionally, you can also take a look at the Enterprise Bot template (https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/tree/master/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/csharp/EnterpriseBotTemplate/EnterpriseTemplate or you can download the VSIX in Visual Studio) and the Virtual Assistant (https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/tree/master/solutions/Virtual-Assistant/src/csharp/assistant) templates available in the Microsoft/AI repo.